# Escolher cor em <input type="submit"...>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, input

Como eu poderia definir uma cor para o `input`. Abaixo tenho um dos `input` que utilizo.

```
<input type="submit" id="Submit69" class="btn btn-default btn-block" value="REP+H4" title="Clique Selecionar as Soluções" />
```

O valor do texto consigo alterar, mas como fazer com que tivesse uma paleta de cor e poder escolher qual cor poderia definir para o `input`?

Answer (score 1):

Alterar css diretamente no componente input:

```
<input type="submit" id="Submit69" class="btn btn-default btn-block" style="background-color: #aaaaaa"
value="REP+H4" title="Clique Selecionar as Soluções" />
```

Alterar via classe css:

```
<style>
   .backgroundModificado {
       background-color: #abcdef;
   }
</style>
<input type="submit" id="Submit69" class="btn btn-default btn-block backgroundModificado" style="background-color: #aaaaaa"
        value="REP+H4" title="Clique Selecionar as Soluções" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe o plugin ColorPicker para jQuery, acho que serve pro seu caso:

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/